# Ethernet Connection Failing

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, 23.04

I've been having some weird behavior with my ethernet connection, it sometimes works for a while after restarting and then fails with "Connection Failed" "Activation of network connection failed". Never works again after that. Wi-Fi works perfectly.

I'm running Ubuntu 23.04, no dual boot, was using kernel driver r8169, downgraded to r8168 without any changes.

I've tried different cables and different networks just to rule out any router configuration issues.

Kernel: 6.2.0-31-generic

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3`

```
30:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1558:65f5]
    Kernel driver in use: r8168
    Kernel modules: r8168
```

Relevant output of `lshw -C network`

```
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:30:00.0
       logical name: enp48s0
       version: 15
       serial: d4:93:90:1e:0b:cf
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.051.02-NAPI duplex=full latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:19 ioport:5000(size=256) memory:80604000-80604fff memory:80600000-80603fff
```

I've looked (admitedly not in great detail) at the pins in the port and nothing looks broken.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update: just noticed this weird behavior on settings when connection is turned off.

[image]

Comment: try "sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager"

Comment: Wi-Fi reconnects immediately, Ethernet took a while and now it's showing as connected but I have no internet, I'm unable to ping anything on my local network `ping: connect: Network is unreachable`

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Comment: I purged r8168 and so far seems to be working, I'll update tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same issue on my Acer Aspire 5 laptop.
Ubuntu 22.04.3 - kernel 6.2.0-32 I found this confirmed bug on this issue:
[https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2031537](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2031537)